# How to get trigger details associated with a task in task scheduler from powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, robocopy

So, basically i need to get the trigger details associated with a task which is created in task scheduler.
[image]

So, basically I want these information which i am going to be set in this trigger window such as its daily or weekly and repeat task duration as well as for a duration of etc.

Right now am able to get following information.

```
Name            : LastTaskResult
Value           : 0
CimType         : UInt32
Flags           : Property, ReadOnly, NotModified
IsValueModified : False

Name            : NextRunTime
Value           : 23-09-2015 11:26:56
CimType         : DateTime
Flags           : Property, ReadOnly, NotModified
IsValueModified : False

Name            : NumberOfMissedRuns
Value           : 0
CimType         : UInt32
Flags           : Property, ReadOnly, NotModified
IsValueModified : False

Name            : TaskName
Value           : test_Task
CimType         : String
Flags           : Property, Key, NotModified
IsValueModified : False

Name            : TaskPath
Value           : 
CimType         : String
Flags           : Property, Key, NotModified, NullValue
IsValueModified : False
```

So, basically my requirement is i have two servers. One is primary and other one is backup. I have scheduled the tasks in primary servers and periodically mirroring(robocopy) these tasks to backup server which works absolutely fine.

But when i change the trigger details or arguments in action tab it does not appear in backup server as i am just checking the task name is already present or not in backup server, if not am creating those tasks.

So is there any way to check the details regarding trigger(Daily or weekly etc, repetition details) or action(script and argument details) so that i can update the tasks accordingly in my seconadary server.

Answer (score 4):

Is something like this what you are after:

```
$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Adobe Flash Player Updater"
$taskTrigger = $task.Triggers[0]

$taskTrigger
```

It should give you an output similar to:

```
Enabled            : True
EndBoundary        : 
ExecutionTimeLimit : 
Id                 : 
Repetition         : MSFT_TaskRepetitionPattern
StartBoundary      : 2000-01-01T09:58:00+09:30
DaysInterval       : 1
RandomDelay        : 
PSComputerName     :
```

Edit: Another way of doing this, using a ComObject connection instead

You could do it something like this:

```
$taskService = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
$taskService.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)

$rootTaskFolder = $taskService.GetFolder("\")
$task = $rootTaskFolder.GetTask("Adobe Flash Player Updater")
$task
```

This will return the definition of the task. You could then use `Compare-Object` to see if it's the same on the backup server, and if not, export/import the task.

If you wanted to parse the XML you could do something like:

```
$parsedXML = [xml]$task.xml
```

You can then compare triggers by doings something like:

```
Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $remoteServerParsedXML.GetElementsByTagName("Triggers") -ReferenceObject $parsedXML.GetElementsByTagName("Triggers")
```

Does this get closer to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: note that this cmdlet is only available for windows 2012+ or windows 8.1+

Comment: ran the query, it only provides:-
Enabled            : True
EndBoundary        : 
ExecutionTimeLimit : 
Id                 : 
Repetition         : MSFT_TaskRepetitionPattern
StartBoundary      : 
Delay              : 
StateChange        : 3
UserId             : 
PSComputerName     :

Comment: it does not prvide whether it is weekly or daily and repeatation time etc

Comment: one more thing can you tell how to get the task creation date using powershell

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably think this is ugly, but it gets you all the pertinent info on the screen. Or you can keep it as an object you can manipulate or format from there...

```
$ScheduledTasks = get-scheduledtask | ? {$_.TaskPath -like '*Cool*'}

foreach ($item in $ScheduledTasks) {

    [string]$Name       = ($item.TaskName)
    [string]$Action     = ($item.Actions | select -ExpandProperty Execute)
    [datetime]$Start    = ($item.Triggers | select -ExpandProperty StartBoundary)
    [string]$Repetition = ($item.Triggers.Repetition | select -ExpandProperty interval)
    [string]$Duration   = ($item.triggers.Repetition | select -ExpandProperty duration)

    $splat = @{

    'Name'       = $Name
    'Action'     = $Action
    'Start'      = $start
    'Repetition' = $Repetition
    'Duration'   = $Duration

    }

    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -property $splat

    $obj | Write-Output
}
```

It will get you something like this:

```
Repetition : PT1H
Duration   : P1D
Name       : MyCoolTask
Action     : C:\MyPath\MyCoolTask\MyCoolTask.exe
Start      : 1/10/2014 3:00:00 AM
```

The repetition is every hour (hence the 1H in the PT1H)
The Duration is the max run time (1 day)
The Name is obviously the name of your task, action and start time should also be self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is "basically" ;)  an export/import function of your tasks.
Here is a sample code :

```
#connect to scheduler of you master server
$sch = New-Object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
$sch.connect("$computername")

$root=$sch.GetFolder("\") 
$folder =$sch.GetFolder("\subfolder") #if you tasks are defined in a subfolder

#Export all tasks in the subfoder to $path folder in xml format
$folder.getTasks(0) | % {
    $path="c:\temp\tasks\$($_.name).xml" 
    New-Item -ItemType file -Path $path
    Set-Content -Path $path -Value $_.xml
}


#connect to scheduler of you backup server
$sch.connect("$backupcomputername")
$folder =$sch.GetFolder("\subfolder")

#import .xml from $task_path
$cred=get-credential # will ask for the credential of the user who run the tasks
Get-childItem -path $task_path -Filter *.xml | %{
    $task_name = $_.Name.Replace('.xml', '')
    $task_xml = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $task = $sch.NewTask($null)
    $task.XmlText = $task_xml
    $folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task_name, $task, 6, $cred.UserName, $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password, 1, $null)
}
```

Comment: yeah , i have already implemented this, the problem arises when i update trigger in primary server , then after importing i need to just check whether any changes in the trigger details then only i need to import it again or update the trigger accordinglt

Comment: I'm not following... why not export / import all the tasks after any modification ? the exported xml contains the triggers details

Comment: the thing is that we are peridiocally updating the tasks in back up server

Comment: can you please tell me how to get task creation date usning powershell ?

Comment: sorry kayasax i want creation date not task name

Comment: `$root.GetTasks(0)|%{[xml]$x=$_.xml ; $x.Task.RegistrationInfo.date} `

Comment: ok thanks.. Is there any other way to get the info directly from file stored in Winodw Task Library?