# How to Get Friendly Description For Scheduled Task Trigger in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/32732879/1378356, I can get a scheduled task's trigger using this syntax:

```
$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SomeTaskName"
$taskTrigger = $task.Triggers[0]
$taskTrigger
```

But how do I see the friendly name (which is displayed in the Task Scheduler UI), such as "At 8:00 am every Monday"?

Comment: What is `$taskTrigger.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 How would the typename of  the object help?

Comment: @Matt Knowing its members.  If it's a datetime object, you can utilize a format operator.

Comment: It's a `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance` which has multiple properties that you could infer the friendly name from but there would be a lot of logic to build that friendly name from beyond the simplest of triggers. you have to check Repetition, StartBoundary,   DaysInterval etc. Getting the one for the UI might just be a matter of invoking the correct dll which the OP is likely looking for.

Comment: What's the "OP"?

Comment: I have posted a script to do this in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086583/how-can-i-get-the-text-that-is-displayed-for-a-trigger-of-a-windows-scheduled-ta/78109839#78109839